# Can Liquibase detect if it has already run?

Tags: liquibase

I have a small set of scripts that manage the build/test/deployment of an app. Recently I decided I wanted to switch to Liquibase for db schema management. This script will be working both on the developer machines where it regularly blow away and rebuild their database and also on deployed environment where we will only be adding new changesets.

When this program first runs on a deployed environment I need to detect if Liquibase has run or not and then run `changelogSync` to sync with the existing tables.

Other than manually checking if the database changelog table exists is there a way for the Liquibase API to let me know that it has already run at least once?

I'm using the Java core library in Groovy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably `((StandardChangeLogHistoryService) ChangeLogHistoryServiceFactory.getInstance().getChangeLogService(database)).hasDatabaseChangeLogTable()`

The ChangeLogHistoryService interface returned by liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogHistoryServiceFactory doesn't have a method to check if the table exists, but the StandardChangeLogHistoryService implementation does.

Comment: So when I try to get that I get a class cast exception. I assume that is because I've never registered my database connection with this factory. Looking at the code it's not obvious to me how to do that?

Comment: I'd need more details on the class cast exception to know for sure what the problem is.

Comment: Just doing exactly the code you provided I get: Cannot cast object 'liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogHistoryServiceFactory@412beeec' with class 'liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogHistoryServiceFactory' to class 'liquibase.changelog.StandardChangeLogHistoryService'

Comment: Sorry, was missing the call to get the changeLogService from the ChangeLogHistoryServiceFatory. I added .getChangeLogService(database) into the example.